# Android Studio Can't Use Packages

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated to Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5 and it's not letting me build projects with packages.

I created a blank project, added a package with one empty class in it, imported the class in my main activity, and got this error when I tried to build the project:

```
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task
':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
.../TestApp/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/example/testapp/mypackage (Is a directory)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried creating different projects ?

Comment: ``added a package with one empty class in it`` ??? If dosn't have class, how to android studio understand what are you try import. The error say ``com/example/testapp/mypackage`` is  a directory, not file

Comment: @ShreeKrishna This was a different project, after it didn't work for another one

Comment: So i think its imported project then, its not the fault of android studio 2.0. Check package name correctly.